# How do I set up a cloud variable server?

Tags: cloud, exe, mit-scratch

I'm forking a code editor that uses block. It is called TurboWarp, it is based on Scratch.
When i package a project to make it an exe, I have the option for my own cloud variable server. How do I set this up on my website?

I'm using https://packager.turbowarp.org to make my exe, https://turbowarp.org/ to make my code, and Wordpress is my website designer. I've tried finding a cloud variable plugin, but without luck. Please help!

Thanks for your time,
Best Codes

Comment: Have you checked this? https://github.com/TurboWarp/cloud-server

Comment: Thanks SO much for your reply, @Ruud Helderman! Yes, I have seen it, but I'm not sure how to integrate it with WordPress. Any tips?

Comment: Carefully read the documentation. From [README.md](https://github.com/TurboWarp/cloud-server#readme): "You can do a similar thing in TurboWarp with the cloud_host URL parameter: `https://turbowarp.org/?cloud_host=ws://localhost:9080/`" I suppose you just have to replace `turbowarp.org` with the address of your TurboWarp web server, and `ws://localhost:9080/` with the address and port of your cloud variable server. If you want to make this public, then you will have to expose _both_ servers to the internet. You may want to find yourself an affordable hosting provider that supports Node.js.

Comment: @BestCodes Your best bet is probably to write your own Wordpress plugin. Find a PHP Websockets implementation, then translate the cloud server's source code into PHP.